# Multiple foreign keys on same column in SQL

Tags: sql

My requirement is to create multiple foreign keys on same column in a table.

Should data in primary keys of two tables be the same or different?

Can primary key data in table 1 and table2 be different?

I need conditions to check before creating two foreign keys on same column.

Comment: Can you show us a 3 table example of what you're expected to implement.

Comment: Table A has data 1, 2 in id column and Table B has data 3, 4 in id column and in Table C i need both data 1,2,3,4 in id colum ( which has foreign keys).is this possible?

Comment: The answer is no. Provide a complete [mcve] if you want a second opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has been asked before:
[Foreign Key referring one field of two tables in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397482/foreign-key-referring-one-field-of-two-tables-in-oracle)

Short answer is, you can't (assuming I'm understanding your question correctly). You probably want to rethink the design.