# SQL sub-types with overlapping child tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design, sql-server-2012

[image: Problem Visual]

Consider the problem above where the 'CommonChild' entity can be a child of either sub-type A or B, but not C. How would I go about designing the physical model in a relational [SQL] database?

Ideally, the solution would allow...

1. for an identifying relationship between CommonChild and it's related sub-type.
2. a 1:N relationship.

### Possible Solutions

1. Add an additional sub-type to the super-type and move sub-type A and B under the new sub-type. The CommonChild can then have a FK constraint on the newly created sub-type. Works for the above, but not if an additional entity is added which can have a relationship with sub-type A and C, but not B.
2. Add a FK constraint between the CommonChild and SuperType. Use a trigger or check constraint (w/ UDF) against the super-type's discriminator before allowing a new tuple into CommonChild. Seems straight forward, but now CommonChild almost seems like new subtype itself (which it is not).
3. My model is fundamentally flawed. Remodel and the problem should go away.

I'm looking for other possible solutions or confirmation of one of the above solutions I've already proposed.

Thanks!

---

EDIT

I'm going to implement the exclusive foreign key solution provided by Branko Dimitrijevic (see accepted answer).

I am going to make a slight modifications in this case as:

1. the super-type, sub-type, and "CommonChild" all have the same PKs and;
2. the PKs are 3 column composites.

The modification is to to create an intermediate table whose sole role is to enforce the exclusive FK constraint between the sub-types and the "CommonChild" (exact model provided by Dimitrijevic minus the "CommonChild's" attributes.).  The CommonChild's PK will have a normal FK constraint to the intermediate table.

This will prevent the "CommonChild" from having 2 sets of 3 column composite FKs. Plus, since the identifying relationship is maintained from super-type to "CommonChild", [read] queries can effectively ignore the intermediate table altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need a variation of [exclusive foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317463/533120):

```
CREATE TABLE CommonChild (
    Id AS COALESCE(SubTypeAId, SubTypeBId) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY,
    SubTypeAId int REFERENCES SubTypeA (SuperId),
    SubTypeBId int REFERENCES SubTypeB (SuperId),
    Attr6 varchar,
    CHECK (
        (SubTypeAId IS NOT NULL AND SubTypeBId IS NULL)
        OR (SubTypeAId IS NULL AND SubTypeBId IS NOT NULL)
    )
);
```

There are couple of thing to note here:

- There are two **NULL-able** FOREIGN KEYs.
- There is a CHECK that allows **exactly one** of these FKs be non-NULL.
- There is a computed column `Id` which equals one of the FKs (whichever is currently non-NULL) which is also a PRIMARY KEY. This ensures that:

  - One parent cannot have multiple children.
  - A "grandchild" table can reference the `CommonChild.Id` directly from its FK. The `SuperType.Id` is effectively popagated all the way down.
  - We don't have to mess with NULL-able UNIQUE constraints, which are problematic in MS SQL Server (see below).

---

A DBMS-agnostic way of of doing something similar would be...

```
CREATE TABLE CommonChild (
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    SubTypeAId int UNIQUE REFERENCES SubTypeA (SuperId),
    SubTypeBId int UNIQUE REFERENCES SubTypeB (SuperId),
    Attr6 varchar,
    CHECK (
        (SubTypeAId IS NOT NULL AND SubTypeAId = Id AND SubTypeBId IS NULL)
        OR (SubTypeAId IS NULL AND SubTypeBId IS NOT NULL AND SubTypeBId = Id)
    )
)
```

Unfortunately a UNIQUE column containing more than one NULL is not allowed by MS SQL Server, which is not the case in most DBMSes. However, you can just omit the UNIQUE constraint if you don't want to reference `SubTypeAId` or `SubTypeBId` directly.

Comment: Filtered indexes can be used in SQL Server to enforce a unique constraint that ignores `null`s

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, but that would be an index and not a UNIQUE constraint, so it couldn't be (for example) referenced by a FOREIGN KEY and its violations would be reported to clients differently (if that's important). Furthermore, there is a philosophical argument against mixing physical and logical concepts.

Comment: SQL Server allows unique indexes to be referenced by FKs. It doesn't allow unique *filtered* indexes to be though.

Comment: +1 for the computed primary key syntax using COALESCE...I've come across the same scenario a few times and while I figured out the two nullable FK's and the CHECK constraint, I never figured out how to implement the Primary Key that way. It looks so obvious now! Elegant!

Answer (score 3):

Wondering what am I missing here?

Admittedly, it is hard without having the wording of the specific problem, but things do feel a bit upside-down.

---

[image]

Comment: I thought about adding an additional hierarchy, but it wouldn't make sense in this particular case plus restrict A & B and A & C from having a common child.

Really my "CommonChild" entity should be its own independent entity. The various sub-types should make references to the CommonChild via FK references or association tables. This is an intermediate normalized model of a very un-normalized (and poor) data model from a late 70s mainframe.