# How can I enforce that a record be a child of only one record when it can be a child of several tables?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm brainstorming how to restructure the contact information of a database.  As you know, phone numbers can be linked to a person (cell phone), to a family (home phone), to an organization/business, etc.  Logically, a phone number is a phone number is a phone number.  There's no real difference between a cell phone number and a home phone number.  And a person can have multiple cell phones, a family can have multiple phone lines, and an organization can have many many phone lines.

Normally, when designing tables, that means there should be a single phone number table.  And it should link in a one to many to persons or families or organizations.  The rub is, how would someone enforce that a phone record is only owned by a single parent record, whether that record be a person record, or a family record, or an organization record?

The only two ways I've figured out are kludges, in my opinion.  I want an elegant solution.

The first is to create 3 tables, PersonPhones, FamilyPhones and OrganizationPhones.  Then you've got 3 tables whose mission is to store essentially the same data.

The second is to create a single phone table with a weird structure.  It would have phone number, a nullable field for a person id, another for a family id and a third for an organization Id.  Then add a constraint that enforces that 2 of those 3 are NULL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can have 3 columns in your PhoneTable (Person_Id,Phone_Number, and Phone_Details). In the Phone_Details column you can mention whether its a cell phone or home or organization. Then you can define a unique key on the combination of Person_Id and Phone_Details.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not a good idea - the DBMS won't be able to enforce the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two ways to deal with a situation like that:

- One way is to use **inheritance** - crate a "PhoneOwner" table that will be the logical parent of a Person, Family, Organization and any other entity that needs to be able to have a phone. Then just link the Phone to the PhoneOwner.
- The other is to use **exclusive foreign keys**, which you already described in your question.

Neither is ideal and you'll have to decide which one better fits your needs.

See also: ["What is the best design for a database table that can be owned by two different resources, and therefore needs two different foreign keys?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317463/533120)