# Database entity with more than one possible parent type

Tags: database-design, relational-database, data-modeling

I have a relational database with an Address entity that should have a parent Address or a parent Unit, but not both.  Currently the schema is Address having a ParentUnitID field and an ParentAddressID field.  Is there a way to change this that prevents an Address from having both a parent Address and a parent Unit at the same time, but retains the foreign key constraints?

Comment: Add a `CHECK` constraint, enforcing that exactly one of the FKs is non-null. This _might_ need to be implemented by a trigger, depending on your DBMS.

Comment: You could have foreign key constraints to both possible parents (i.e. two distinct foreign key columns) and then a CHECK constraint that ensures one or the other is always NULL.

Comment: You should propose this as an answer so he can select it as the answer

Comment: Define unit, what is unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FOREIGN KEY is not enforced on a NULL value, so you just need to make sure that only one of them is non-NULL:

```
CHECK (
    (ParentUnitID IS NOT NULL AND ParentAddressID IS NULL)
    OR (ParentUnitID IS NULL AND ParentAddressID IS NOT NULL)
)
```

If you happen to use MySQL, you'll need to implement this  as a trigger, since MySQL [doesn't enforce CHECK constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14248038/533120).

Alternatively, you could use inheritance, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317463/533120).