# Rails: polymorphic association, different options depending on type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I'm building a diet analysis app in Rails 4.1. I have a model, `FoodEntry`, which at a simple level has a `quantity` value and references a `Food` and a `Measure`:

```
class FoodEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :food
  belongs_to :measure
end
```

However I actually have two different types of measures, standard generic measures (cups, teaspoons, grams, etc.) and measures which are specific to a food (heads of broccoli, medium-sized bananas, large cans, etc.). Sounds like a case for a polymorphic association right? e.g.

```
class FoodEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :food
  belongs_to :measure, polymorphic: true # Uses measure_id and measure_type columns
end

class StandardMeasure < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :food_entries, as: :measure
end

class FoodMeasure < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :food_entries, as: :measure
end
```

The thing is, the food-specific measures come from a legacy database dump. These records are uniquely identified by a combination of their `food_id` and `description` - they aren't supplied with a single-column primary key (`description` is not unique on its own because there are multiple foods with the same measure description but different numeric data). Because I'm importing to my Rails Postgres db, I'm able to add a surrogate primary key - the auto-incrementing integer `id` column that Rails expects. But I don't want to utilize this `id` as a reference in my `FoodEntry` model because it poses a pretty big challenge for keeping referential integrity intact when the (externally-supplied) data is updated and I have to reimport. Basically, those `ids` are completely subject to change, so I'd much rather reference the `food_id` and `description` directly.

Luckily it's not very difficult to do this in Rails by using a scope on the association:

```
class FoodEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :food
  belongs_to :measure, ->(food_entry) { where(food_id: food_entry.food_id) }, primary_key: 'description', class_name: 'FoodMeasure'
  # Or even:           ->(food_entry) { food_entry.food.measures }, etc.
end
```

Which produces a perfectly acceptable query like this:

```
> FoodEntry.first.measure
FoodMeasure Load (15.6ms)  SELECT  "food_measures".* FROM "food_measures"  WHERE "food_measures"."description" = $1 AND "food_measures"."food_id" = '123' LIMIT 1  [["description", "Broccoli head"]]
```

Note that this assumes that `measure_id` is a string column in this case (because `description` is a string).

In contrast the `StandardMeasure` data *is* under my control and doesn't reference `Foods`, and so it makes perfect sense to simply reference the `id` column in that case.

So the crux of my issue is this: I need a way for a `FoodEntry` to reference only one type of measure, as it would in the polymorphic association example I made above. However I don't know how I'd implement a polymorphic association with respect to my `measure` models because as it stands:

- an associated `FoodMeasure` needs to be referenced through a scope, while a `StandardMeasure` doesn't.
- an associated `FoodMeasure` needs to be referenced by a string, while a `StandardMeasure` is referenced by an integer (and the columns being referenced have different names).

How do I reconcile these issues?

---

**Edit:** I think I should explain why I don't want to use the autonumber `id` on `FoodMeasures` as my foreign key in `FoodEntries`. When the data set is updated, my plan was to:

1. Rename the current `food_measures` table to `retired_food_measures` (or whatever).
2. Import the new set of data into a new `food_measures` table (with a new set of autonumber ids).
3. Run a join between these two tables, then delete any common records in `retired_food_measures`, so it just has the retired records.

If I'm referencing those measures by `food_id` and `description`, that way I get the benefit that food entries automatically refer to the new records, and therefore any updated numeric data for a given measure. And I can instruct my application to go searching in the `retired_food_measures` table if a referenced measure can't be found in the new one.

This is why I think using the `id` column would make things more complicated, in order to receive the same benefits I'd have to ensure that every updated record received the same `id` as the old one, every new record received a new not-used-before `id`, and that any retired `id` is never used again.

There's also one other reason I don't want to do this: ordering. The records in the dump are ordered first by `food_id`, however the measures for any given `food_id` are in a non-alphabetical but nevertheless logical order I'd like to retain. The `id` column can serve this purpose elegantly (because ids are assigned in row order on import), but I lose this benefit the moment the ids start getting messed around with.

So yeah I'm sure I could implement solutions to these problems, but I'm not sure it would be worth the benefit?

Comment: See also: [What is the best design for a database table that can be owned by two different resources, and therefore needs two different foreign keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13317463/533120)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it poses a pretty big challenge for keeping referential integrity
>   intact when the (externally-supplied) data is updated

This is an illusion. You have total control over the surrogates. You can do exactly the processing of external updates whether they are there or not.

This is just one of those times when you want your own new names for things, in this case Measures, of which FoodMeasures and StandardMeasures are subtypes. Have a measure_id in all three models/tables. You can find many idioms for simplifying subtype constraints, eg using type tags.

If you process external updates in such a way that it is convenient for such objects to also have such surrogates then you need to clearly separate such PutativeFoodMeasures and FoodMeasures as subtypes of some supertype PutativeOrProvenFoodMeasure and/or of PutativeOrProvenMeasure.

EDIT:

Your update helps. You have described what I did. It is not difficult to map old to new ids; join on old & new (food_id,description) and select old id (not a food_id!). You control ids; how can it matter to reuse ids compared to them not even existing otherwise? Ditto for sorting FoodMeasures; do as you would have. It is only when you mix them with StandardMeasures giving some result that you need order a mixture differently; but you would do that anyway whether or not a shared id existed. (Though "polymorphic:" may not be the best id sharing design.)

The Measures model offers measures; and when you know you have a FoodMeasure or StandardMeasure you can get at its subtype-particular parts.

Comment: I'm having a hard time interpreting your answer. Could you give an example of how you would do it?

Comment: Have you read Branko's comment's link? Re Measures:  Your Measures-FoodMeasures-StandardMeasures is his notifiable-users-groups.