# DB Design for Choosing One of Multiple Possible Foreign Tables

Tags: database, database-design, schema

Say if I have two or more vastly different objects that are each represented by a table in the DB. Call these Article, Book, and so on. Now say I want to add a commentening feature to each of these objects. The comments will behave exactly the same in each object, so ideally I would like to represent them in one table.

However, I don't know a good way to do this. The ways I know how to do this are:

- Create a comment table per object. So have Article_comments, Book_comments, and so on. Each will have a foreign key column to the appropriate object.
- Create one global comment table. Have a comment_type that references "Book" or "Article". Have a foreign key column per object that is nullable, and use the comment_type to determine which foreign key to use.

Either of the above ways will require a model/db update every time a new object is added. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one other strategy: **inherit**<sup>1</sup> different kinds of "commentable" objects from one common table then connect comments to that table:

[image]

All 3 strategies are valid and have their pros and cons:

1. Separate comment tables are clean but require repetition in DML and possibly client code. Also, it's impossible to enforce a common key on them, unless you employ some form of inheritance, which begs the question: why not go straight for (3) in the first place?
2. One comment table with multiple FKs will have a lot of NULLs (which may or may not be a problem storage and cache-wise) and requires adding a new column to the comments table whenever a new kind of "commentable" object is added to the database. BTW, you don't necessarily need the `comment_type` - it can be *inferred* from what field is non-NULL.
3. Inheritance is not directly supported by current relational DBMSes, which brings its own set of [engineering tradeoffs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037398/533120). On the up side, it could enable easy addition of new kinds of commentable objects without changing the rest of the model.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Aka. category, subclassing, generalization hierarchy... For more on inheritance, take a look at "Subtype Relationships" section of [ERwin Methods Guide](http://tangra.si.umich.edu/~radev/654/resources/ERMGALL.PDF).*

Comment: The third approach would be great... but how does one implement it? Do any ORMs natively support this? In practice, would it be essentially the 1st option?

Comment: @tomo.otsuka Please follow the link for some hints at the inheritance implementation - there are 3 main variants (each with its own pros and cons). I'm not sure about ORM support.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think your first option is best, but I'll throw this option in for style points:

Comments have a natural structure to them.  You have a first comment, maybe comments about a comment.  It's a tree of comments really.

What if you added one field to each object that points to the root of the comment tree.  Then you can say, "Retrieve the comment tree for article 123.", and you could take the root and then construct the tree based off the one comment table.

Note: I still like option 1 best. =)