# How to relate 3 tables depending on event

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a table that have information about different types of events that can be done by persons in two categories **civil and worker**

so for each one of them I have their respective tables

```
civil{  civil_id, name, age,telephone...} the  primary key is civil_id

worker{ worker_id, name, duty, department...} the  primary key is worker_id
```

then the event table has a list of all possible events

```
event {type_of_event} the  primary key is type_of_event
```

then I am planing to store information in other table

with eventype, the person that did the job (worker or civil)

```
id  event_type       date      person
-----------------------------------
1   type1         12-12-12     x 
2   type1         05-12-10     y
3   type2         02-12-12     y
```

Now in this design I do not know how to relate whose person did the job if, I would had only a kind of person (aka civil) i would only store the civil_id in person field in this last table....but how to know if it was civil or worker, do I need other intermediate table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this can, you cannot set up a `foreign key` because you have multiple parent. In order to do fast search or to avoid `full table scan` define an index on column `person` on table `event` and join the table using `LEFT JOIN`. eg,

```
SELECT  ....,
        COALESCE(b.name, c.name) AS personname
FROM    event a
        LEFT JOIN civil b
            ON a.person = b.civil_id
        LEFT JOIN worker c
            ON a.person = c.worker_ID
```

Adding `INDEX`

```
ALTER TABLE event ADD INDEX (person)
```

Comment: I have done a sqlfiddle, could you please point out your solution, I had an error in event table http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4829/1

Comment: i have slight changes. I added another column on table event to identity which person belongs to. here, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de457/3

Answer (score 7):

Generally, there are to ways to model this type of situation...

### Using Exclusive Foreign Keys

[image]

In the `event`, both `civil_id` and `worker_id` are NULL-able, but there is also a constraint ensuring **exactly one** of them is non-NULL at any given time:

```
CHECK (
    (civil_id IS NOT NULL AND worker_id IS NULL)
    OR (civil_id IS NULL AND worker_id IS NOT NULL)
)
```

### Using Inheritance<sup>1</sup>

[image]

For more on inheritance, take a look at "Subtype Relationships" chapter in the [ERwin Methods Guide](http://tangra.si.umich.edu/~radev/654/resources/ERMGALL.PDF) and at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037398/533120).

---

*<sup>1</sup> Aka. category, subtyping, subclassing, generalization hierarchy...*