# Foreign Key column mapped to multiple primary keys

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a database which has three tables

Messages - PK = MessageId
Drafts - PK = DraftId
History - FK = RelatedItemId

The History table has a single foreign Key `[RelatedItemId]` which maps to one of the two Primary keys in `Messages` and `Drafts`.

Is there a name for this relationship?

Is it just bad design?

Is there a better way to design this relationship?

Here are the CREATE TABLE statements for this question:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[History](
    [HistoryId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RelatedItemId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_History] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [HistoryId] ASC )
 )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Messages](
    [MessageId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Messages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (    [MessageId] ASC )
 )


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Drafts](
    [DraftId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Drafts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (  [DraftId] ASC )
)
```

Comment: would be better to provide `CREATE` statements. In some rdbms you can retrieve it like `SHOW CREATE TABLE Messages;`

Comment: I found it hard to choose an answer, thus rolled a dice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice I have found is to create a Function that returns whether the passed in value exists in either of your Messages and Drafts PK columns. You can then add a constraint on the column on the History that calls this function and will only insert if it passes (i.e. it exists).

Adding non-parsed example Code:

CREATE FUNCTION is_related_there ( 
   IN @value uniqueidentifier )
RETURNS TINYINT
BEGIN
   IF (select count(DraftId) from Drafts where DraftId = @value + select count(MessageId) from Messages where MessageId = @value) > 0 THEN
      RETURN 1;
   ELSE 
      RETURN 0;
   END IF;
END;

ALTER TABLE History ADD CONSTRAINT
    CK_HistoryExists CHECK (is_related_there (RelatedItemId) = 1)

Hope that runs and helps lol

Comment: A great answer, I am hoping to see what other people think!

Comment: It is actually an approach that used for handling multi-level inheritance in a data-centric architecture. Have seen it used in both Java and .net applications

Answer (score 5):

In a short description the solution you have used is called: 
**Polymorphic Association** 
*Objective*: Reference Multiple Parents
*Resulting anti-pattern:* Use dual-purpose foreign key, violating first normal form (atomic issue), loosing referential integrity 
*Solution:* Simplify the Relationship 
[More information about the problem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557).

BTW createing a common super-table will help you:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a name for this relationship?

There is no standard name that I'm aware of, but I've heard people using the term "generic FKs" or even "[inner-platform effect"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).

> Is it just bad design?

Yes.

The reason: it prevents you from declaring a FOREIGN KEY, and therefore prevents the DBMS from enforcing referential integrity directly. Therefore you must enforce it trough imperative code, which is [surprisingly difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20873843/533120).

> Is there a better way to design this relationship?

Yes.

Create separate FOREIGN KEY for each referenced table. Make them NULL-able, but make sure exactly one of them is non-NULL, through a CHECK constraint.

Alternatively, take a look at [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17015847/533120).

Comment: Does the answer by Talspaugh27 allay your concerns about referential integrity?

Comment: @bnieland Well, it allows two connections, where you specifically stated it "maps to one". But even assuming that's fixed, I don't see how it would avoid the race condition I mentioned in the link. And it's DBMS-specific (not just syntactically, some DBMSes don't support a CHECK that references other rows or tables at all). And it probably doesn't perform as well as "native" FK. And is less obvious and self-documenting. OK, I'll stop bashing it now ;)

Comment: @bnieland That being said, a careful implementation of a similar idea (that avoids the race condition) can save you a bunch of NULLs, but NULLs tend to be cheap anyway (especially under MS SQL Server, Oracle slightly less, YMMV).