# MySQL, how to restructure optional multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

For this example, I'm trying to build a system that will allow output from multiple sources, but these sources are not yet built. The output "module" will be one component, and each source will be its own component to be built and expanded upon later.

Here's an example I designed in MySQLWorkbench:
[image: table layout]

The goal is to make my output module display data from the output table while being easily expanded upon later as more sources are built. I also want to minimize schema updates when adding new sources. Currently, I will have to add a new table per source, then add a foreign key to the output table.

Is there a better way to do this? I don't know how I feel about these NULL-able foreign keys because the JOIN query will contains IFNULL's and will get unruly quickly.

Thoughts?

**EDIT 1: Clarification**

I will be displaying a grid using data in the output table. The output table will contain general data for all items in the grid and will basically act as an aggregator for the output_source_X tables:

```
output(id, when_added, is_approved, when_approved, sort_order, ...)
```

The output_source_X tables will contain additional data specific to a source. For example, let's say one of the output source tables is for Facebook posts, so this table will contain columns specific to the Facebook API:

```
output_source_facebook(id, from, message, place, updated_time, ...)
```

Another may be Twitter, so the columns are specific for Twitter:

```
output_source_twitter(id, coordinates, favorited, truncated, text, ...)
```

A third output source table could be Instagram, so the output_source_instagram table will contain columns specific to Instagram.

There will be a one-to-one foreign key relationship with the output table and ONLY ONE of the output_source_X tables, depending on if the output item is a Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, etc... post, hence the NULL-able foreign keys.

```
output table
------------
foreign key (source_id_facebook) references output_source_facebook(id)
foreign key (source_id_twitter) references output_source_twitter(id)
foreign key (source_id_instagram) references output_source_instagram(id)
```

I guess my concern is that this is not as modular as I'd like it to be because I'd like to add other sources as well without having to update the schema much. Currently, this requires me to join output_source_X on the output table using whatever foreign key is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design in almost certainly bad in a few ways.

It's not that clear what your design is representing but a straightforward one would be something like:

```
// source [id] has ...
source(id,message,...)
// output [id] is approved when [approved]=1 and ...
output(id,approved,...)
// output [output_id] has [source_id] as a source
output_source(output_id,source_id)
foreign key (source_id) references source(id)
foreign key (source_id) references source(id)
```

Maybe you have different subtypes of outputs and/or sources? Based on sources and/or outputs? Maybe each source is restricted to feeding particular outputs? Are "outputs" and "sources" actually *kinds* of outputs and sources, and this is info not on how outputs are sourced but info on what kinds of output-source pairings are permittted?

Please give us statements parameterized by column names for the basic statements you want to make about your application. Ie for the application relationships you are interested in. (Eg like the code comments above.) (You could do it for the diagrammed design but probably that would be overly complicated and not really reflecting what you are trying to model.)

Re your EDIT:

> There will be a one-to-one foreign key relationship with the output
>   table and ONLY ONE of the output_source_X tables, depending on if the
>   output item is a Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, etc... post, hence the
>   NULL-able foreign keys.

You have a case of multiple disjoint subtypes of a supertype.

Your situation is a lot like that of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078218/doctrine-orm-linking-foreign-key-to-multiple-tables) except that where they have a subtype discriminator/tag column indicating which subtype table you have a set of columns where the non-empty one indicates which subtype table. See Erwin Smout's & my answers. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27183834/3404097).

> Please give us statements parameterized by column names for the basic
>   statements you want to make about your application

and you will find straightforward statements (as above). And if you give the statements for your current design you will find them complex. See also this.

> I guess my concern is that this is not as modular as I'd like it to be
>   because I'd like to add other sources as well without having to update
>   the schema much.

Your structure is not reducing schema changes compared to proper subtype designs.

Anyway, DDL is there for that. You can genericize subtypes to avoid DDL only by loss of the DBMS managing integrity. That would *only* be relevant or reasonable based on evaluating DDL vs DML performance tradeoffs. Search re (usually, anti-pattern) EAV.

(*Only* after you shown that creating & deleting new tables is infeasible and the corresponding horrible integrity-&-concurrency-challenged mega-joining table-and-metadata-encoded-in-table EAV information-equivalent design is feasible should you consider using EAV.)

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to work with my question. I've edited my original question with what I think will answer your questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a lot to process, but I think your suggestion about EAV may be viable. I had used a similar pattern before (I just didn't know it was called that) but hadn't thought of applying it here. Regardless, thanks for the extra resources.