# Specify foreign key on one column and the value of another column

Tags: sql, database, database-design, schema, polymorphic-associations

I have a table `ASSETS` that has a structure as it is shown below :

```
----------------------------------------------------
ID (PK) | DESCRIPTION | TYPE | Do- | Do+ | Dx- | Dx+
----------------------------------------------------
```

`TYPE` column has a *foreign key*, possible values are `SECURITY` or `CURRENCY` (i.e. *FX*), also I have two more tables : `CURRENCIES` (*for example*, `EUR`, `RUB` or `USD`) :

```
--------------------------------------------------------
ID (PK)| FROM (FK ASSETS.ID) | TO (FK ASSETS.ID) | VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------
```

and `SECURITIES` (*for example*, `MTS`, `GAZP` or `VTB`) :

```
----------------------------------------------------------
ID (PK)(FK ASSETS.ID)| CURRENCY (PK)(FK ASSETS.ID) | VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------
```

How I can make a constraint, that not only acts like foreign key in `CURRENCIES.FROM`, `CURRENCIES.TO` and `SECURITIES.CURRENCY`,but also checks if referring `ASSETS.TYPE` is `CURRENCY`, and in `SECURITIES`  also checks if referring `ASSETS.TYPE` for `SECURITIES.ID`  is `SECURITY`?

I guess I can write triggers to check `ASSETS.TYPE` value, but I am searching for another solution right now (*if it is possible, of course*).

*If there are better ways to do the things a want (as a better database design), please, share your ideas.*

*P.S. I guess it is quite a common problem, so if there are articles about it or similar questions asked on this network or some general-case-solutions, feel free to share.*

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26093733/3404097). (That particular question confusedly partly has no Student table (your ASSESTS_DATA) in its original text but has one in its Edit diagram.) Your 1st design is like the one I suggest (relationally straightforward) (1st set of bullets), and yours can be modified/CHECKed as I suggest (second set of bullets)

Comment: @philipxy : as I've tagged my question, FireBird.

Comment: On a first glance it looks strange to me to treat Securities and Currencies as just two types of assets. One (Security) is something that has a value - be it a building, a mere certificate of debt or whatever - whereas the other (Currency) is just a unit of measure. I would rather couple Securities and *Money*, with Money being cash in different currencies, money in various bank accounts, etc.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner : _FX_ and _Securities_ have almost the same set of properties, like it is shown above and in such procedures like finding a portfolio cost or initial (+ adjusted initial) and minimum margins they are treated like an asset, not money or security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to your original question is to use an additional `CHECK` *constraint* like :

```
CREATE TABLE CURRENCIES (
   ...
   CONSTRAINT c_asset_from CHECK(exists(select 1 from ASSETS a where a.id = from and a.type = 'CURRENCY'))
);
```

And similar constraion for `TO` field and in `SECURITIES` for `CURRENCY` field.
But I think your new design, with separate *FK* for `security` and `currency`, is better design.

Comment: a.id = from? What does that mean? And when I try something similar I get 'Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.' Thus no select from different table. How is this working for you?

Comment: Different database engines support different features. The question was originally tagged as `FireBird` which support that. I guess you use mySql which doesn't

Answer (score 2):

IMO technically the design could be criticized in two categories:

- Having a dual-purpose foreign key in Asset table called **`type`** ([Polymorphic
  Association anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177776/foreign-key-column-mapped-to-multiple-primary-keys/22179608#22179608)). 
   That will violating first normal form (atomic
  issue), loosing referential integrity.
   A solution could be
  simplification of the relationship by inheritance.
   Having a base
  table for Currency and Security tables called `Money`,containing shared properties of them, like `name`. 
  primary key of Money table will be primary key of `Currency` and `Security` tables.
  Having foreign key of `Money` inside `Asset` will be the solution.
- Using [surrogate identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) on Asset tables, that will result
  losing business logic in schema design.
   I will prefer haveing
  composite primary key in Asset Table `PK{ID, TYPE(money fk)}`.
   Then having
  check constraints on `CURRENCIES` and `SECURITIES`  will solve the
  problem.
   
  `CURRENCIES_chk {FK.CURRENCY = FK_TO.Money && FK.CURRENCY = FK_FROM.Money} 
   SECURITIES_chk {FK.SECURITY = FK.Money}` 
   
  [image]

Comment: There was an idea like: table `ASSET_TYPE` (one field `ID`, possible values `SECURITY`/`CURRENCY`), table `MONEY` (not a good name choice for this table, but in grace of the compatibility with your answer I am leaving it as it is) (two fields, `ID`, `TYPE` (`FK` to the `ASSET_TYPE.ID`)). And a trigger to insert either in the `SECURITIES` table or `CURRENCIES` (`FX`, choosing the right words) upon the `MONEY.TYPE`. I guess I can use only one trigger for solving that issue. In your design I see only one flow : I can put securities like `GAZP` in `CURRENCY` table and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. In my answer there is not any Triggering mechanism, just two check constraints exist! May be I haven't understand the domain of your design. lets flow a scenario step by step to see what will happen. First we define  `GAZP` as a row in Security?

Comment: I don't think that you haven't understood the concept, I just don't know how to make sure that securities won't go to currencies table(aka fx) and vice versa.in addition, they all should be in the  money table.

Comment: In SECURITIES table The CHECK CONSTRAINT between SECURITY.FK = ASSET.TYPE wouldn't guaranty that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use checks for this.
Do you want to hardcode these values?

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    P_Id int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT chk_Person CHECK (P_Id>0 AND City='Sandnes')
)
```

Source: [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

And using firebird might require different syntax. 
Take a look at: [Firebird reference](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-ddl-table.html)

Comment: The Firebird `CHECK` syntax is the same.

Comment: In your example you check the columns of the same table, but can you provide an example that points to the value of the column from another table?

Comment: @notulysses In that case you might be better off with either rethinking your model, or to use triggers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that declaratively by changing the design of your keys and using identifying relationships.

Here is the blueprint:

[image]

Look how `ASSET.ASSET_TYPE` is propagated through both "branches", only to be merged in the `SECURITY.ASSET_TYPE`.

Since `SECURITY.ASSET_TYPE` is just one field, one `SECURITY` row can never connect to multiple asset types. To say it slightly differently: if `ASSET` and `CURRENCY` are connected to the same `SECURITY`, they must have the same `ASSET_TYPE`.

In addition to that, `CURRENCY` can never point to `ASSET`s of different type.

You can bring back your old surrogate keys (and other fields) into this model as necessary.

---

That being said, generating `ASSET_NO` presents some challenges.

- You can just use `auto-incrementing` mechanism built-into your `DBMS`, but that would leave "holes" (i.e. two different asset types will never use the same integer, even though they technically can).
- Or you can find the next value manually, but you'll have to handle concurrency in that case (either serialize insertions through locking, or retry insertion in case concurrent transaction tried the same value).