# Drawing with MySQL Workbench (noob)

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

Sorry for the potentially stupid question but I'm a total noob. The thing is I'm trying to do the exercises for the book *Database Systems: Design, Implementation and Management*. This book is built with Microsoft Visio in mind to do the EERDs. The thing is I didn't want to pay so I downloaed the **MySQL Workbench** (I don't have anything else installed yet as I'm just doing design exercises for now).

Well, my problem is I reached a point where they're asking me to do the diagram representing supertypes and subtypes with the different constraints: total completeness, partial completeness, disjoint subtypes or overlapping subtypes. The book represents this with a circle and a line.

The thing is I don't have the minimum idea as to how to draw this on Workbench. I can do the relationships, primary keys, foreign keys, etc. But I can't seem to find how to draw supertypes/subtypes and constraints.

Could anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

p.s.: google search didn't produce the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK MySQL Workbench allows you to make physical models only, whereas your book seems to show you conceptual models on its pages. You can use some tool that can draw conceptual models and then convert them to physical ones or DB generation scripts, or, you can perform conversion in your brains and draw physical model right away taking in mind what conversions have been done. Some information couldn't be represented after conversion, and you should write it in comments on tables or columns in MySQL Workbench not to forget to implement them later in triggers, for example, or in some other manner.

Comment: oh, what a shame! So I'll have to do them by hand. :( I refuse to buy Visio. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This maybe looks like one answer from [Can MySQL Workbench's EER Diagram editor represent tables with relationships that are partial/total disjoint/overlap specialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382339/can-mysql-workbenchs-eer-diagram-editor-represent-tables-with-relationships-tha)

> Ok i think i have found the solution! If you click a line between two entities you ll see 2 boxes for each side of the connection that says Mandatory. This is total participation. At least it worked for me. You ll notice that total participation has no O on the side that participates but if you uncheck it you ll get a partial participation with O on the side of the entity.

Is this what you are looking for?